# Именительный падеж

Tags: грамматика, падежи

Как понятие определяется и именуется - это и есть именительный падеж? Ну тогда пример с самолётом: 
1) Видим сам самолёт и говорим - это самолёт; 
2) Видим в небе белую полосу, оставленную самолётом, а самолета не видим, но по полосе говорим - это самолёт. 
В первом случае - прямое определение, во втором - косвенное. 
По этим признакам можно сказать, что Именительный падеж всё-таки имеет деления на части как и другие падежи (второй родительный, второй предложный)?

Answer (score 1):

А с чего Вы взяли, что

> как понятие определяется и именуется - это и есть именительный падеж?

Вспомним изначальное значение названий падежей.
И названия падежей, и само слово «падеж» мы заимствовали у греков. Основоположником учения о падежах является учёный-энциклопедист Аристотель (384-322 гг. до н.э.). В качестве грамматического термина Аристотель использовал греческое слово ptosis – буквально падение – заимствованное из практики игроков в кости. Словом падение и обозначался до 16 века термин падеж.

Именительный падеж – это падеж, который просто что-либо называет по имени – именует. Впервые название Именительный падеж в 16 веке употребил Милетий Смотрицкий, автор одной из первых русских грамматик. Падеж правый (позже именительный) калькируется с греческого orte и даёт правильную, или исходную форму слова. Филолог конца XVI века Максим Грек называл этот падеж прямым. Все остальные падежи являются по отношению к нему косвенными (или косыми, греческое plagiai)

Первыми название для него придумали греки — onomastike prosis [ономастика птозис]. Римские ученые перевели эти слова на латынь: casus nominativus [казус НОМИНАТИВУС]. И греческое onoma [онома], и римское nomin [номен] одинаково значили «ИМЯ».

В грамматиках «новых европейских языков» сохранилось название номинатив для падежа, который считается основной формой существительного (в английском, немецком, французском языках). Мы перевели это слово на русский как ИМЕНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ (тот, который именует, называет).

Родительный падеж до Смотрицкого называли «родственное падение». Вспомним греческий корень GEN («род»). Родительный падеж можно было бы назвать еще «родительским» падежом. В латинском языке он звался Genetivus casus [ГЕНИТИВУС казус], что можно истолковывать как «падеж родства»: сын своего отца, внук Льва Толстого, потомки Пушкина.

Это можно распространить и шире, если «родство» понимать не в узком, прямом смысле. Говоря «ветка пальмы», мы представляем себе ветку, которая «рождена» пальмой.

Таким было ИСХОДНОЕ, НАЧАЛЬНОЕ значение этого падежа. Затем он приобрел и разные другие оттенки значения, например, понятие о части, отделенное от целого (родительный отделительный):

Вороне где-то послал кусочек (чего?) СЫРУ.

«Круг сыра» как бы породил, произвел свой отдельный кусочек. Можно и здесь, хоть и с натяжкой, вывести теперешний смысл из первоначального.

У именительного падежа такого разделения нет: каким бы образом имя ни появилось, оно будет именем, **прямым падежом, начальным, главным** по сравнению с остальными - косвенными. Недаром и дополнение прямое то, которое имеет форму винительного падежа без предлога, оно совпадает по форме с именительным падежом неодушевлённого предмета (вижу стол) и обозначает прямое действие.

Answer (score 0):

Если не манипулировать упрощённым определением именительного падежа, которое вы сначала привели, а затем подвергли критике, то понимать его можно так:

1. **Самолёт** - это такая штуковина, которая... (определение)
2. Название этого аппарата: **самолёт**. (именование)

Comment: Во-первых, написано не существительное "определение", а глагол "определяется". Написано четко, что происходит действие по определению, выявлению понятия. Во-вторых, понятие определяется только тогда, когда оно видимо что ли?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос, сейчас стало совершенно непонятно, чего вы хотите и что понимаете под "делением именительного падежа".

Comment: Во-первых. Если именование происходит разными способами (а их два общих (так сказать), а потом ещё четыре уточняющих), то можно ли эти способы признавать делениями падежа? Во-вторых, в общественности Именительный падеж - только прямой, но из примера видно же, что это не так.

Comment: Теперь понятно. Именительный падеж всегда **прямой**, в противоположность всем косвенным падежам (независимо от позиции в составе предложения): http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6

Comment: Та часть, где самолет был определен напрямую - прямой. Та часть, где самолет был определен по косвенным признакам - косвенный. И так у всех падежей, значит ли это, что все падежи - прямые?

Comment: Именительный падеж там - только в части "- это самолёт", другие падежи косвенные (творительный и родительный).

Comment: Вот те раз! А часть со следом от самолёта - никакой падеж?

Comment: Родительный ("самолёта") - или вы другие существительные рассматриваете?

Comment: Когда по следу от самолета говорят о самом самолете, то сам самолёт - Именительный падеж?

Comment: Самолёт в предложении примера 2 - в трёх _разных_ падежах, при каждом упоминании - в своём (в самом конце - в именительном).

Comment: Ага, значит косвенно его выясняли?

Comment: Падеж не зависит от способа его выяснения :) .

Comment: Вы отрицаете такую человеческую способность? Предлагаете не замечать её?

Answer (score 0):

Разделение падежей на косвенные и именительный не связано с тем, по каким признакам определяется то или иное явление. Нет разницы между предложениями и ситуациями, в которых они использованы:

1. Какая большая полоса на небе! Это **самолет** пролетел.
2. Смотри, по небу летит **самолет**!

В обоих случаях именительный падеж существительного *самолет* указывает на то, что именно *самолет* является исполнителем действия (летит/пролетел), его субъектом.

Comment: Дело в том, что "полоса" - не сам "самолёт". Из полосы сделан вывод о самолёте - косвенный. Именование произошло через полосу.

Comment: @Игорь2 это не имеет совершенно никакого значения для русской грамматики (особенно в отношении существительных), по каким признакам мы поняли, что пролетел самолет или что-либо еще. В обоих случаях один и тот же именительный падеж. Именительный падеж именует, называет предмет, при этом не обращая внимание ни на что боле, кроме как на сам предмет(ы).

Comment: А тут именование косвенное. Когда именование прямое - то имеем дело с самим понтием. а когда именование через свойства, признаки понятия, то оно - косвенное. Так же с Родительным и Предложным.